Ngrx action does not trigger on module initialization
I am implementing the NgRx Effects module using the standalone API and something strange is happening to me.
I have the following module, which registers a series of actions and effects:
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        provideState({ name: 'chat', reducer: chatReducer }),
        provideEffects(ChatEffects),
    ],
    declarations: [ChatComponent],
})

/**
 * Chat module
 */
export class ChatModule {
    constructor(private readonly store: Store) {
        console.log('ChatModule');
        this.store.dispatch(CreateChatComponent());
    }
}

In the module constructor, I launch an initialization action like this:
constructor(private readonly store: Store) {
  console.log('ChatModule');
  this.store.dispatch(CreateChatComponent());
}

However, the action is not triggered in any case. However, if I add a timeout to the dispatch, then I see that the action is triggered. What could be the reason?
export class ChatModule {
    constructor(private readonly store: Store) {
        console.log('ChatModule');
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.store.dispatch(CreateChatComponent());
        }, 1000);
    }
}


UPDATE:
Try calling the method from a factory service.
export function myFactory(store: Store) {
     return () => this.store.dispatch(CreateChatComponent());
}

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        provideState({ name: 'chat', reducer: chatReducer }),
        provideEffects(ChatEffects),
        {
            provide: 'someService',
            useFactory: myFactory,
            deps: [Store],
            multi: true
        },
    ],
    declarations: [ChatComponent],
})

/**
 * Chat module
 */
export class ChatModule { }

Looks like some sort of timing issue, you can solve it by moving the this.store.dispatch(CreateChatComponent()); to the root component level.
@Component({
    ...
})
export class ChatComponent {
    ...
    constructor(private readonly store: Store) {
        console.log('ChatComponent');
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.store.dispatch(CreateChatComponent());
        }, 1000);
    }
    ...
}


this could be a solution, but there are cases in which the module does not provide any component, but the effects perform some business logic without the intervention of components, so the solution would not work.

@MarcFernandez updated my answer!
